# Link dependencies for specific flavors with dimensions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an android app which has two types: free and premium. Each tier has 2 versions: lightweight and heavy.
Here's the Gradle implenetation of this:

```
flavorDimensions "tier", "distro"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "tier"
    }
    premium {
        dimension "tier"
    }
    lightweight {
        dimension "distro"
    }
    heavy {
        dimension "distro"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a `.jar` dependency for the premium tier *only*. The way to add it is quite trivial:

```
premiumImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // Works
```

The problem is that I have two versions of this `.jar` . One for each subversion mentioned above: `lightweight` and `heavy`.

I tried to apply the trivial solution to this type of dependency:

```
premiumLightweightImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*lightweight.jar'])
premiumHeavyImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*heavy.jar'])
```

But I get a gradle error:

> Could not find method premiumLightweightImplementation() for arguments
>   [directory 'libs']

Of course this also applies to premiumHeavyImplementation.

I'm sure there's a gradle-way to do what I'm asking.
I found two options to deal with this issue:

1. Stop using dimensions altogether (Bad solution, I'll have to write all the flavor-combinations myself).
2. Implement a function which retrieves the current flavor I'm trying to assemble, and use its return value in a directory path. For example:

   def combination = getCurrentFlavorCombination()
   premiumImplementation fileTree(dir: "libs/$combination", include: ['*.jar'])

These are ugly and unreliable ways to achive this simple requirement:
The premium tier should have a .jar linked to it - the version of that .jar depends on another dimension - distro.

I'm not asking for too much, but couldn't find in Gradle docs a nice way to do that. I only found ways to compile a library into jars, but mine already comes in jars, I only wish to link it appropriately. Maybe you guys can help me out here.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does your preferred solution work if you explicitly declare the corresponding configurations, like `configurations { premiumLightweightImplementation }`?

Comment: @PeterLedbrook OMG this ACTUALLY WORKS!!! Please write this as an answer so I can mark this as solved. I thought that gradle wouldnt understand the link between the configuration name and the variant I'm assembling. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was going by [this section](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-configurations) of the Android Studio manual which states that you need to declare explicitly any configurations that for flavor/build type combinations. In this case, that means you need to add the following to your build script before the `dependencies {}` block:

```
configurations {
    freeLightweightImplementation
    freeHeavyImplementation
    premiumLightweightImplementation
    premiumHeavyImplementation
}
```

Comment: What if I am adding a module or library project instead of a jar. I am trying to use like below but not working.

implementation project(':Library') was working. Now I replaced it with
freeDebugImplementation project(path:':Library') and paidDebugImplementation project(path:':Library')

Is there any other rule for the library module?

Comment: @ParmeshwarC You do not need to specify debug/release for libs, it will be done automatically