# specific flavor dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having issues specifying different dependencies for `debug` and `release` build types combined with dimensions.

In my `app.gradle` I specified **1 dimension** and **2 productFlavors**, like so:

```
android {

    [...]

    flavorDimensions "tier"
    productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "tier"
        }
        paid {
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to specify different dependencies for all the build variants (**freeDebug**, **freeRelease**, **paidDebug**, **paidRelease**), and I tried doing it like so:

```
dependencies {
    freeDebugImplementation "com.someDependency:free-debug:1.0.0";
    paidDebugImplementation "com.someDependency:paid-debug:1.0.0";

    freeReleaseImplementation "com.someDependency:free-release:1.0.0";
    paidReleaseImplementation "com.someDependency:paid-release:1.0.0";
}
```

However, this fails with

```
Could not find method freeDebugImplementation() for arguments [com.someDependency:free-debug:1.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Maybe I'm approaching this requirement the wrong way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S I'm using version `3.1.2` of the android gradle plugin, and version `4.7` of the gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This section](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-configurations) of the Android Studio manual indicates that you need to explicitly declare variant configurations before you use them, i.e. with this:

```
configurations {
    freeDebugImplementation
    paidDebugImplementation
    freeReleaseImplementation
    paidReleaseImplementation
}
```

I don't know whether that's still the case, but worth a shot.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043256/link-dependencies-for-specific-flavors-with-dimensions

Comment: It worked. Thanks! (I would prefer not to have to do this though)

Comment: Is there any better way to set dependencies for multiple flavors because I have more than 10 flavors.